# Correct usage of Promise in js

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm pretty new to javascript, and can't seem to figure this one out myself:
I want to use a plugin in my Cordova project that handles storage.
Basically, I want this:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('download_quality')=="4k")
```

to be replaced by a native storage plugin.
Data is stored via:

```
    this.nativeStorage.setItem('download_quality',"4k")
        .then(
        () => console.log('Stored item!'),
        error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
    );
```

According to the docs, I should use:

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('download_quality').then(
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.error(error)
);
```

This works fine, but how can I use this in an if-statement?

I've tried:

```
var test = this.nativeStorage.getItem('download_quality').then(
            data => {return data},
            error => console.error(error)
        );
if(test=="4k")
...
```

but that doesn't work.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you should approach this is in the promise way, do your stuff inside it.

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('download_quality').then(
  data => {
    if (data === '4k') {
      // do something
    }
  },
  error => console.error(error)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES7

```
async yourMethod() {
    try {
        const data = await this.nativeStorage.getItem('download_quality');
        if (data === '4k') {
            // do something
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment to `test` is actually a reference to the `Promise`. Since you will be accessing the native storage, that access will be done asynchronously. A `Promise` is just a representation of a future result.

You need to put the if statement inside a function that will be called when the promise is resolved. That function will receive the data returned by `getItem` and then you can do whatever you want with it.

Like:

```
function checkDownloadQuality (downloadQuality) {
  if (downloadQuality === "4k") {
    // do something
  }
}
this.nativeStorage.getItem('download_quality').then(
    data => checkDownloadQuality(data),
    error => console.error(error)
);
// or if the nativeStorage API support it:
this.nativeStorage.getItem('download_quality')
   .then(checkDownloadQuality)
   .catch(error => console.error(error));
```